# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getName()' on Android 10

Tags: android, file, nullpointerexception, android-10.0

I am getting Image from user to upload it.
The method I am using works fine upto Android 9 (Pie).
But I tested it on Android 10 and it give me Null Pointer.
I am getting the file name, I think it has something to do with new permissions policy, but I can't resolve.

Here is the complete error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65536, result=-1, data=Intent 
    
    {dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/

253155/ORIGINAL/NONE/image/jpeg/1274443360 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list 
    
    U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages

%2Fmedia%2F253155/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/1274443360} }}

to activity {com.buraqsysstudio.welist/com.buraqsysstudio.welist.Activities.MainActivity}: 
    
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String 

java.io.File.getName()' on a null object reference
```

Here is how I am opening chooser Intent:

```
Permissions.check(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, null, new PermissionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onGranted() {
                Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                getIntent.setType("image/*");
                Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                pickIntent.setDataAndType(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "image/*");
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{pickIntent});
                PICK_IMAGE = 1;
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });
```

This is the code to send Image:

```
Uri fullPhotoUri = data.getData();
                    user_profile_image.setImageURI(fullPhotoUri);
                    file = new File(FileUtils.getPath(fullPhotoUri, getActivity()));
                    Log.d("filedata", "=>" + file);
                    File finalAvatar = ViewUtils.saveBitmapToFile(file);
                    userAvatar = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData
                            ("avatar", finalAvatar.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), finalAvatar));
```

Does anyone help me with this issue. Thanks

Comment: `if(file==null) return;` Dont use a pointer if it is null. You could display a Toast there to inform the user.

Comment: Use `fullPhotoUri` too to upload the file.

Comment: There are a lot of changes in Android 10, which includes the way apps works with files. Read this to get more information about how you can work with files. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

Comment: Get rid of `FileUtils.getPath()`.